# Input from is only 1 in html

Tags: python, html, django

Input from is only 1 in html.Im making Login form in index.html like

```
<form class="my-form" action="{% url 'accounts:regist_save' %}" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_username">Username</label>
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.username.errors }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_email">Email</label>
        {{ form.email }}
        {{ form.email.errors }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="id_password1">Password</label>
        {{ form.password1 }}
        {{ form.password1.errors }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class ="control-label" for="id_password2">Password(Conformation）</label>
          {{ form.password2 }}
          {{ form.password2.errors }}
          <p class="help-block">{{ form.password2.help_text }}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="SEND">
        </div>
      </div>
      {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
```

in forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

in urls.py like

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^login/$', login,{'template_name': 'index.html'},name='login'),
]
```

Only Username field is shown in browser, but others are not there.By using Google validation,only Username field has input tag, but others do not have.Why does it happen?How should i fix this?

Comment: are you using django's builtin auth login view ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal yes, i am

Comment: In that case you have to specify the form as well in the urls. url(r'^login/$',
    login,
    {'template_name': 'index.html', 'authentication_form': RegisterForm},
    name='auth_login',
),

Comment: Another mistake is that you calling the login view. But from the form, it seems you want do the registration ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal oh,i see.yes,I wanna do the registration.